# Prove that a continuous function from a compact metric space to any metric space is closed.

Tags: general-topology, functions, proof-explanation

My problem is as stated in the title. Primarily, I am looking for if anyone could give me a hint. It would be very appreciated, I am not seeking after a full proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: What can you say about a closed subset of a compact space? Is that property preserved by a continuous map? How do you conclude the image is closed?

Comment: (+1) Nice hint!

Comment: @EclipseSun  I have written a proof that a continuous function from a compact metric space is compact. Can I conclude by saying that a compact set (any) is bounded and **closed**, therefore QED? (I don't know if this is correct, seems a bit "lazy")

Comment: @CarlSchmidt Yes, only need to combine the results we've already known.

Comment: To the proposer: The continuous image of a compact space is compact. A compact subset of a Hausdorff space  is closed.  Some students assume that any closed bounded subset of a metric space must be compact, which is false. "Bounded" is not a topological property: If $(X,d)$ is any metric space then the metric $e(x,y)=\min(d(x,y),1)$ generates the same topology that $d$ does, and with respect to $e$, the whole space $X$ is closed and bounded

Answer (score 0):

Closed subsetst of a compact space are compact. The image of a compact set with respect to a continuous function is continuous. Compact subsetst are closed.

Comment: Compact subsets of a Hausdorff space are closed. Metric spaces are Hausdorff. Compact subsets of non-Hausdorff spaces need not be closed.